# Oracle mkdir command broken after update

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently upgraded sqldeveloper to 22.x, I can't remember the previous version it was on. Now commands such as mkdir and spool are failing on scripts I used to run daily.

For example

```
host mkdir "C:\Users\Isaac\Requests\"
```

This script was completely unchanged and now it fails with

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Spool also fails with

> SP2-0556: Invalid file name.

Again, this was a script I would run every single day, for the past year. I can't find what is causing this. Any ideas would be really helpful.

Comment: Just updated my sqldeveloper and found a workaround: just try `host "mkdir C:\Users\Isaac\Requests"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "quotes"

```
clear screen

host mkdir c:\Users\JDSMITH\Requests\

cd c:\Users\JDSMITH\Requests\

spool regions.csv

select /*csv*/ * from regions;

spool off

!type regions.csv
!dir
```

[image]

There's a chance this is a side effect of going to Java 11 from Java 8.

If you need a directory name with spaces, you can also use SQLcl.

See the 'sql.exe' in your bin directory, or download latest from oracle.com/sqlcl

[image]

*Disclaimer: I'm an Oracle employee and a product manager for SQL Developer.*

Comment: Thank you! This helps a bunch. Unfortunately removing the quotes, does not allow me to create directories with spaces, special Character in them, such as "Engineering - Networks/Requests" 

Is there another workaround for this?

Spool still fails with SP2-0556:Invalid file name

Example:

spool "C:\Users\Isaac\Engineering\&&ticketnumber\output_&&username..LOG"

Without quotes I get 'ILLEGAL SPOOL COMMAND'

Comment: workaround: it's working in SQLcl, which is the command line for SQL Developer, i'll update my answer @IsaacEfik